# Invalid XAML suddenly in DataTemplate for longlistselector items (WP8)

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, datatemplate

Had this error a few days ago and it seemed to go away. Now it wont go away.  I am also getting an Adcontrol error: **ApplicationId and AdUnitId need to be set before using this control** Adcontrol is set up the exact same way in another app so I don't see what the issue is and cant find any information on it.

**EDIT:
If I remove the portion of the code with double brackets }}, the Invalid Error goes away. I removed the Adcontrol all together to isolate the error as well. However, when I run the app, I still get this:**

```
**A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll

    Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit.resources, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.**
```

I have uninstalled and reinstalled WPToolkit. Im using similar code and WPToolkit in another app and it does not give me this error. What else can I do?

INVALID XAML:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="SoundTileDataTemplate">
    <StackPanel>
        <Grid Margin="0,5,6,0" Height="100" Width="140"
              toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True">
            <Border BorderBrush="#FF49A609" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="3,3,3,3" Background="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" Opacity=".6"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" FontSize="19" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="140"  FontFamily="/BBSM;component/Fonts/123Sketch.ttf#123Sketch" TextAlignment="Center" />
            <Image Source="/Assets/tiles/TRXHSBRGIcon.png" Width="30" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,6,6" Visibility="{Binding Status, Converter={StaticResource DownloadStatusToIconVisibilityConverter}}" />
            <ProgressBar Height="12" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Padding="0" Margin="0" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" Value="{Binding DownloadProgress}" Visibility="{Binding Status, Converter={StaticResource DownloadStatusToProgressBarVisibilityConverter}}"/>
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="ExtrasTileDataTemplate">
    <StackPanel>
        <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
            <toolkit:ContextMenu IsZoomEnabled="False" >
                <toolkit:MenuItem Header="Save as Ringtone"  Command="{Binding SaveSoundAsRingtone}" CommandParameter="{Binding FilePath}" />
            </toolkit:ContextMenu>
        </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
        <Grid Margin="0,5,6,0" Height="100" Width="140"
              toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True">
            <Border BorderBrush="#FF49A609" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="3,3,3,3" Background="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" Opacity=".6"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" FontSize="19" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="140"  FontFamily="/BBSM;component/Fonts/123Sketch.ttf#123Sketch" TextAlignment="Center" />
            <Image Source="/Assets/tiles/TRXHSBRGIcon.png" Width="30" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,6,6" Visibility="{Binding Status, Converter={StaticResource DownloadStatusToIconVisibilityConverter}}" />
            <ProgressBar Height="12" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Padding="0" Margin="0" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" Value="{Binding DownloadProgress}" Visibility="{Binding Status, Converter={StaticResource DownloadStatusToProgressBarVisibilityConverter}}"/>
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Adcontrol:

```
<UI:AdControl ApplicationId="*********" AdUnitId="******" Width="480" IsAutoRefreshEnabled="True" Grid.Row="1" Height="80"/>
```

When I run the project I get the following. I continue after each one, and the app runs, but the Pivot Headers are all screwed up but app seems functional.

```
A first chance exception of type 'Microsoft.Advertising.Shared.AdException' occurred in Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.DLL

Additional information: You can not use PubCenter IDs for testing in the emulator. If you want to test with these IDs, please deploy your application to a device. Otherwise please change your ApplicationId to "test_client" and AdUnitId to one of the supported ad types as outlined in the documentation.

A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll

Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit.resources, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Comment: What's the error? or is the ApplicationID thing the only one?

Comment: @ChrisW. The only other error says Invalid XAML.  Both errors when I click on them point to the DataTemplates above. Very weird

Comment: Just out of curiosity, can you open it in Blend and get the same error?

Comment: @ChrisW. Yep, same error. And just like Visual Studio, the entire DataTemplate is underlined, so its not as if it isolates it.

Comment: Interesting, sometimes I'll run into those oddball "invalid xaml" errors and it won't do it in blend yet it still runs fine. Nice mystery, guess we can see if someone smarter comes along to educate us.

Comment: @ChrisW. I added some errors when I run the project.  Ive never received an error about using a real Ad Id before in an Emulator. The ad just wont show up which is fine.  Ill try re-installing WPToolkit

Comment: Few days before same problem for my ListBox Datatemplate. This post helped me. Just Give a try. Let me know http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/fb20c0e2-e16b-4ff6-8ada-40791bb4e416/invalid-xaml?forum=silverlightcontrols#63ab033e-292b-4bd3-a0ee-92bccbd6af59

Comment: Are you definitely referencing the Advertising assembly correctly? It seems to be moaning about that? Check your references/clean/rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using  windows phone toolkit  then 
you have to include

```
 xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
xmlns:cc="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls"
```

in your *.xaml page